# Trying to instantiate a JUCE MessangerManager throws “Access violation writing location”

Tags: c++, dll, juce, winui

I am trying to use JUCE as a `dll` backend for a WinUI app. I managed to make it work but it sometimes(almost randomly, because I can't find a pattern, it looks like a timeout) throws `JUCE_ASSERT_MESSAGE_MANAGER_EXISTS`.

[image: throwing JUCE_ASSERT_MESSAGE_MANAGER_EXISTS]

people on the [JUCE Forum](https://forum.juce.com/t/how-to-initialize-juce-to-work-as-a-dll-with-no-gui/51961) suggested to use `initialiseJuce_GUI()`. The problem is that this function calls `MessageManager::instance()` that tries to create one.

For some reason, it throws `Access violation writing location` when entering a `CriticalSection`(Like std::lock for JUCE apps) and I cannot find the cause.

This is the call stack:

[image]

Any ideas of the possible causes of this and how I might solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you get random access violations I would start enabling the address sanitizer. You can find that as part of C++ settings in Visual Studio. It might give you a hint as to where the memory corruption happens.